# UITableView Shadow not coming properly (mis aligned)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, shadow

Am trying to add bottom shadow to UITableViewCell and its coming but misaligned. This is my code and i have uploaded my screenshot also

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 125;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 5;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(indexPath.row==0){
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell1"]];
    // Configure the cell...
    }else if(indexPath.row==1){
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell2"]];
    }else if(indexPath.row==2){
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell3"]];

    }else if(indexPath.row==3){
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell4"]];

    }else {
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cell5"]];

    }
    cell.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
    return cell;
}
```

Screenshot

[image]
How to align that shadow at bottom properly?

Comment: problem with the image that you are setting to the cell, check the size of it and the dimensions of the cell.

Comment: can u explain little more?

Comment: could you see the image being repeated 2 times in certain cells? UIColor's->colorWithPatternImage will repeat it obviously.

Comment: oh....so how can i add as background?

Comment: try adding a UIImageView to the cell or use cell's backgroundView or selectedBackgroundVIew property of UITableViewCell.

Comment: Thanks for your support@satheeshwaran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your code with this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
UIImageView *av = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 277, 58)];
av.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
av.opaque = NO;

if(indexPath.row==0){

// Configure the cell...
    av.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cell1"];
    cell.backgroundView = av;
}else if(indexPath.row==1){
    av.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cell2"];
    cell.backgroundView = av;
}else if(indexPath.row==2){
    av.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cell3"];
    cell.backgroundView = av;
}else if(indexPath.row==3){
    av.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cell4"];
    cell.backgroundView = av;
}else {
    av.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cell5"];
    cell.backgroundView = av;
}

return cell;
```

}